# Duplicate bouncycastle classes using expo-dev-client and expo-updates

Tags: android, react-native, expo, build.gradle

I am getting the following error in an expo project using expo-dev-client (due to native packages):

```
Duplicate class org.bouncycastle.LICENSE found in modules jetified-bcprov-jdk15to18-1.70 (org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15to18:1.70) and jetified-bcprov-jdk18on-1.71 (org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk18on:1.71)

<---- snip 100s of similar error messages all regarding duplicate bouncycastle ------->
```

As for as i have gotten figuring this out i have noticed there are 2 packages using bouncycastle:

- expo-updates
- @onfido/react-native-sdk

It looks like these have a conflicting dependency but i am unable to resolve it.

Does anyone have a clue?

Thanks!

Added multiple configurations to android/app/build.gradle without success.

Example:

```
configurations.all { c ->
    c.resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails dependency ->
        if (dependency.requested.group == 'org.bouncycastle') {
            dependency.useTarget "org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15to18:1.71"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example of build.gradle that works for me.

Note the placement is within allProjects and not buildscript also.

```
buildscript {
    etc..
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            // add dependency substitution rules
            dependencySubstitution {
            substitute module('org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15to18') using module('org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk18on:1.71')
            substitute module('org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on') using module('org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk18on:1.71')
            substitute module('org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk18on') using module('org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk18on:1.71')
            
            substitute module('org.bouncycastle:bcutil-jdk15to18') using module('org.bouncycastle:bcutil-jdk18on:1.71')
            substitute module('org.bouncycastle:bcutil-jdk15on') using module('org.bouncycastle:bcutil-jdk18on:1.71')
            substitute module('org.bouncycastle:bcutil-jdk18on') using module('org.bouncycastle:bcutil-jdk18on:1.71')
            }   
        }
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
etc..
}
```

Comment: It's great to see one Mike helping another